# Android best way to load images from device storage

Tags: android, image, loading

I am loading multiple images locally from devices storage. I am currently using Glide to load them. But Glide is very big library and it offers many features which I don't need at all, for ex. disk cache and loading from internet. Is there any better and more efficient library or another way to load images from devices storage?
The only functionality I need is memory bitmap cache, async loading from Uri and resizing just like in Glide.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I am not explicitly asking for library? Maybe I should only use LRUCache and my own loading mechanism... and someone could recommend this....

Comment: You can use Picasso  http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @Onregs Picasso offers nearly same features as Glide does. I need only small part of them.

Comment: @Onregs I know Picasso. But it is more efficient in terms of loading images from device storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)**, its method count is **~700 compared to ~3200** of Glide, you can save lots of method count here.

I will **recommend you do keep using image library**, it does lots of cool stuff in the background, which requires lots of dev efforts.

- Resizing of images according to view size
- Caching in memory using LRU cache
- Recycling of Bitmaps to free up heap once you are done with displaying
- Disk cache, so that you can load faster on app restart OR eviction from LRU cache
- Proven record of working on fragmented Android ecosystem
- No need to take care of threads, thread pools

Also on top of if you are using [**Proguard** (using `minifyEnabled true` in your **build.gradle** )](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) for code obfuscation, it will strip away methods which are not getting used in your apk